# Trapz giving weird results

Tags: matlab

I'm having a weird result with Matlab's trapz function. I have two variables, zptest and omega, both of which are positive, 3000x2x1 arrays.

When I plot zptest vs omega (plot(zptest(:,1,1),omega(:,1,1)) the curve is clearly positive and should give a positive result when integrating. This is not the case, however, as shown below:

> > trapz(zptest(:,1,1),omega(:,1,1))

ans =

-0.049999940237341

just to prove that both omega and zptest are positive:

> > find(omega(:,1,1) < 0)

ans =

Empty matrix: 0-by-1

> > find(zptest(:,1,1) < 0)

ans =

Empty matrix: 0-by-1

I know I'm not giving any context to what I'm actually doing but this seems like a context independent problem. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try re-ordering x in ascending order (and y-values accordingly):

```
x_order = x(end:-1:1); %fliplr
y_order = y(end:-1:1); %fliplr
trapz(x_order, y_order)
```

In `trapz(x,y)` differentiation of x is applied through diff(x,1,1), i.e. `[x(2:n,:) - x(1:n-1,:)].` If your x is descending this will give negative dx. It doesn't matter if it is positive or negative. However, in `plot` the curve will appear positive-definite (you don't actually see the order of points, just pairs from two vectors on a plane).

**Example** (compare the following):

```
x = [-1 -0.5 0]; y = 0.5-x; 
figure; plot(x,y); hold on; plot(-x, y,'r')
trapz(x, y)
trapz(-x, y)
figure; plot(x, y); hold on; plot(fliplr(-x), fliplr(y),'r')
trapz(fliplr(-x), fliplr(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this. The integral of a function that is always positive, if the limits are inverted, will still be negative. Thus we know that

```
int(x^2,-1,1) = 2/3
```

But

```
int(x^2,1,-1) = -2/3
```

Clearly x.^2 is always a positive number, but here the limits of integration were not increasing, but decreasing.

If the x_i in the call to trapz are not in increasing order, then you will get negative results. This is reflected by trapz. Trapz sees the order of the points as presented to it.

```
x = -1:.1:1;
trapz(x,x.^2)
ans =
         0.67

xrev = fliplr(x);
trapz(xrev,xrev.^2)
ans =
        -0.67
```

And, as pointed out by gevang, the plot shows only that the function is positive, not the order of the points.