# Integral of a distribution returns nan value

Tags: python, scipy

I have a distribution whose point on both axies are:

```
x = [21.381625583382622 ,21.201155495759807 ,21.008654068962123 ,20.90037201638843 ,20.888340677213577 ,20.701854920003328 ,20.62365121536677,
    20.467243806093656 ,20.395055771044525 ,20.196538674659422 ,20.094272291673157,20.040131265386314 ,19.949896221574896 ,19.727316446840085,19.619034394266393 ,19.57090903756697 ,19.33028225406988 ,19.167859175209337 ,19.119733818509914 ,18.975357748411653 ,18.86707569583797 ,18.69863694739 ,18.620433242753442 ,18.578323555641447 ,18.27754007627008 ,18.235430389158086 ,18.169258023696383 ,17.99480360566099 ,17.86847454432501 ,17.76019249175132 ,17.639879100002773 ,17.519565708254223 ,17.278938924757128 ,17.309017272694263 ,17.122531515484013 ,16.990186784560613 ,16.875889062399487 ,16.749560001063514 ,16.64729361807725 ,16.50291754797899 ,16.394635495405296 ,16.26830643406932 ,16.11189902479621 ,16.03369532015965 ,15.91939759799853 ,15.76299018872542 ,15.648692466564295 ,15.540410413990605 ,15.408065683067202 ,15.221579925856952 ,15.071188186171264 ,15.071188186171264 ,14.87267108978616 ,14.75837336762504 ,14.674153993401056 ,14.553840601652508 ,14.409464531554251 ,14.253057122281138 ,14.19891609599429 ,14.036493017133752 ,13.843991590336074 ,13.789850564049226 ,13.669537172300679 ,13.513129763027564 ,13.392816371279016 ,13.266487309943043 ,13.140158248607065 ,12.869453117172833 ,12.82734343006084 ,12.64085767285059 ,12.496481602752333 ,12.370152541416356 ,12.261870488842664 ,12.093431740394694 ,12.003196696583283 ,11.94304000070901 ,11.75655424349876 ,11.600146834225647 ,11.497880451239382 ,11.407645407427971 ,11.19709697186801 ,11.088814919294316 ,10.992564205895478 ,10.830141127034938 ,10.7338904136361 ,10.595530013125268 ,10.469200951789292 ,10.33685622086589 ,10.180448811592775 ,10.07818242860651 ,9.957869036857963 ,9.807477297172277 ,9.687163905423729 ,9.560834844087754 ,9.452552791514059 ,9.29012971265352 ,9.1758319904924 ,9.073565607506133 ,8.953252215757583 ,8.814891815246753 ,8.54418668381252 ,8.441920300826254 ,8.297544230727997 ,8.225356195678867 ,8.050901777643471 ,7.9245727163074955 ,7.82230633332123 ,7.677930263222972 ,7.521522853949859 ,7.425272140551021 ,7.292927409627618 ,7.160582678704215 ,7.010190939018529 ,6.913940225619691 ,6.805658173045997 ,6.625188085423175 ,6.5409687111991905 ,6.4387023282129245 ,6.282294918939812 ,6.149950188016408 ,6.047683805030142 ,5.921354743694167 ,5.776978673595909 ,5.638618273085079 ,5.560414568448522 ,5.40400715917541 ,5.2716624282520055 ,5.127286358153748 ,5.0069729664052 ,4.874628235481797 ,4.730252165383538 ,4.603923104047563 ,4.49564105147387 ,4.321186633438475 ,4.218920250452209 ,4.086575519528806 ,3.9542307886054022 ,3.8218860576819993 ,3.6955569963460233 ,3.5692279350100478 ,3.4188361953243622 ,3.3045384731632415 ,3.196256420589548 ,3.0157863329667256 ,2.9014886108056044 ,2.7992222278193384 ,2.6668774968959355 ,2.534532765972532 ,2.402188035049129 ,2.2878903128880084 ,2.1435142427897502 ,1.993122503104065 ,1.8908561201177987 ,1.7585113891943958 ,1.6381979974458472 ,1.4998375969350168 ,1.3674928660116135 ,1.241163804675638 ,1.1148347433396621 ,0.9824900124162592 ,0.880223629429993 ,0.7298318897443077 ,0.6035028284083319 ,0.471158097484929 ,0.3388133665615254 ,0.21849997481297745 ,0.10420225265185667 ,-0.022126808684119315 ,-0.17251854836980485 ,-0.2868162705309256 ,-0.395098323104619 ,-0.5575214019651598 ,-0.7018974720634175 ,-0.8041638550496835 ,-0.930492916385659 ,-1.056821977721635 ,-1.1951823782324649 ,-1.3215114395684413 ,-1.441824831316989 ,-1.616279249352385 ,-1.7185456323386505 ,-1.850890363262054 ,-1.9651880854231747 ,-2.097532816346578 ,-2.2419088864448353 ,-2.3682379477808118 ,-2.512614017879069 ,-2.6329274096276176 ,-2.7291781230264567 ,-2.9036325410618513 ,-3.011914593635545 ,-3.1382436549715216 ,-3.276604055482351 ,-3.4149644559931813 ,-3.529262178154302 ,-3.64957556990285 ,-3.799967309588536 ,-3.93231204051194 ,-4.034578423498205 ,-4.172938824009036 ,-4.341377572457003 ,-4.455675294618124 ,-4.563957347191818 ,-4.714349086877503 ,-4.852709487388334 ,-4.9549758703746 ,-5.081304931710576 ,-5.243728010571116 ,-5.358025732732237 ,-5.466307785305931 ,-5.62715194579043 ,-5.730997247152738 ,-6.00170237858697 ,-6.140062779097802 ,-6.2603761708463495 ,-6.380689562594897 ,-6.494987284756018 ,-6.657410363616558 ,-6.777723755365107 ,-6.904052816701082 ,-7.042413217211912 ,-7.180773617722744 ,-7.271008661534154 ,-7.409369062044986 ,-7.55976080173067 ,-7.6860898630666465 ,-7.800387585227767 ,-7.962810664088307 ,-8.107186734186566 ,-8.191406108410549 ,-8.32976650892138 ,-8.456095570257354 ,-8.582424631593332 ,-8.672659675404743 ,-8.79297306715329 ,-9.015552841888105 ,-9.117819224874372 ,-9.208054268685784 ,-9.364461677958897 ,-9.484775069707442 ,-9.611104131043419 ,-9.695323505267403 ,-9.875793592890226 ,-10.020169662988483 ,-10.080326358862758 ,-10.26079644648558 ,-10.375094168646703 ,-10.501423229982677 ,-10.65783063925579 ,-10.760097022242057 ,-10.904473092340314 ,-11.024786484088862 ,-11.139084206249985 ,-11.337601302635088 ,-11.373695320159651 ,-11.578228086132183 ,-11.830886208804134 ,-11.95721527014011 ,-12.035418974776668 ,-12.26401441909891 ,-12.408390489197167 ,-12.40237481960974 ,-12.612923255169699 ,-12.751283655680531 ,-12.84753436907937 ,-12.991910439177627 ,-13.12425517010103 ,-13.23855289226215 ,-13.334803605660989 ,-13.503242354108957 ,-13.707775120081488 ,-13.791994494305476 ,-13.88824520770431 ,-14.056683956152279 ,-14.189028687075682 ,-14.309342078824232 ,-14.4777808272722 ,14.598094219020746 ,-14.724423280356723 ,-14.77856430643569 ,-15.019191090140664 ,-15.049269438077802 ,-15.19364550817606 ,-15.33200590868689 ,-15.494428987547431 ,-15.602711040121127 ,-15.692946083932535 ,-15.843337823618223 ,-16.077948937527893 ,-16.132089963814735 ,-16.234356346801 ,-16.38448086486688 ,-16.517092817410095 ,-16.607327861221506 ,-16.727641252970052]

y = [ 14.0 ,20.0 ,16.0 ,12.0 ,8.0 ,12.0 ,22.0 ,16.0 ,18.0 ,24.0 ,17.0 ,22.0 ,15.0 ,13.0 ,16.0 ,30.0 ,16.0 ,9.0 ,11.0 ,4.0 ,9.0 ,24.0 ,22.0 ,11.0 ,    11.0 ,0.0 ,7.0 ,11.0 ,8.0, 14.0 ,13.0 ,9.0 ,4.0 ,33.0 ,27.0 ,27.0 ,26.0 ,32.0 ,18.0 ,23.0 ,26.0 ,27.0 ,21.0 ,17.0 ,33.0 ,27.0 ,32.0 ,24.0 ,31.0 ,34.0 ,14.0 ,27.0 ,22.0 ,26.0 ,17.0 ,22.0 ,21.0 ,11.0 ,37.0 ,24.0 ,34.0 ,20.0 ,29.0 ,26.0 ,25.0 ,34.0 ,26.0 ,12.0 ,28.0 ,18.0 ,20.0 ,20.0 ,25.0 ,18.0 ,36.0 ,22.0 ,20.0 ,29.0 ,19.0 ,17.0 ,16.0 ,6.0 ,17.0 ,11.0 ,25.0 ,12.0 ,21.0 ,31.0 ,29.0 ,20.0 ,11.0 ,9.0 ,0.0 ,21.0 ,24.0 ,8.0 ,12.0 ,6.0 ,16.0 ,24.0 ,17.0 ,16.0 ,10.0 ,18.0 ,15.0 ,3.0 ,8.0 ,12.0 ,10.0 ,11.0 ,7.0 ,16.0 ,12.0 ,30.0 ,23.0 ,27.0 ,28.0 ,33.0 ,29.0 ,27.0 ,25.0 ,44.0 ,40.0 ,47.0 ,48.0 ,55.0 ,75.0 ,75.0 ,71.0 ,91.0 ,92.0 ,83.0 ,120.0 133.0 ,162.0 ,163.0 ,187.0 ,237.0 ,262.0 ,306.0 ,316.0 ,385.0 ,417.0 ,474.0 597.0 ,639.0 ,687.0 ,780.0 ,868.0 ,953.0 ,1079.0 ,1187.0 ,1279.0 ,1431.0 ,1628.0 ,1875.0 ,2180.0 ,2542.0 ,2988.0 ,3406.0 ,3890.0 ,4356.0 ,4824.0 ,5222.0 ,5621.0 ,5834.0 ,5937.0 ,5875.0 ,5838.0 ,5578.0 ,5269.0 ,4847.0 ,4403.0 ,3773.0 ,3335.0 ,2934.0 ,2420.0 ,2132.0 ,1873.0 ,1612.0 ,1425.0 ,1264.0 ,1173.0 ,1030.0 ,925.0 ,857.0 ,768.0 ,684.0 ,614.0 ,   523.0 ,491.0 ,422.0 ,397.0 ,339.0 ,281.0 ,236.0 ,227.0 ,202.0 ,155.0 ,155.0 ,116.0 ,101.0 ,106.0 ,96.0 ,90.0 ,68.0 ,65.0 ,66.0 ,61.0 ,58.0 ,44.0 ,37.0 ,39.0 ,32.0 ,40.0 ,40.0 ,27.0 ,33.0 ,30.0 ,19.0 ,17.0 ,31.0 ,23.0 ,42.0 ,14.0 ,26.0 ,22.0 ,15.0 ,10.0 ,22.0 ,20.0 ,18.0 ,28.0 ,23.0 ,26.0 ,14.0 ,9.0 ,17.0 ,11.0 ,15.0 ,24.0 ,25.0 ,3.0 ,10.0 ,25.0 ,9.0 ,23.0 ,16.0 ,7.0 ,28.0 ,14.0 ,20.0 ,13.0 ,11.0 ,14.0 ,22.0 ,19.0 ,11.0 ,15.0 ,25.0 ,28.0 ,28.0 ,26.0 ,12.0 ,28.0 ,28.0 ,10.0 ,13.0 ,11.0 ,37.0 ,5.0 ,26.0 ,20.0 ,15.0 ,32.0 ,24.0 ,13.0 , 29.0 ,28.0 ,22.0 ,36.0 ,36.0 ,26.0 ,27.0 ,25.0 ,27.0 ,30.0 ,35.0 ,35.0 ,35.0 ,19.0 ,26.0 ,23.0 ,24.0 ,32.0]
```

I want to evaluate the area under the distribution, this is the code I've used:

```
area = simps(y,x)
```

But if I run it, it gives me this error:

> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
>   y[slice1]*hsum*hsum/hprod + 
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add y[slice1]*hsum*hsum/hprod +

I've tried to print the value of the area but it returns `nan` value.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you provide the data with comma(`,`) so that anyone can try your solution that is not working.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot it! I edited the post.

Comment: There are still some commas in between, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I hope this is the right time. There are many data, and it is not easy to check every comma.

Comment: `simps` expects the `x` values to be strictly monotonic.  You have a repeated value in there (`x[50]` and `x[51]`).  Your `x` array is *mostly* decreasing, but there are a few places where `x` increases.  If you fix the order of the values so that the entire array is decreasing, you won't get an error.  But your answer might have the opposite sign of what you expect.  Giving the `x` values in descending order is like integrating "backwards":  the integral from *b* to *a* is the negative of the integral from *a* to *b*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run your code for myself, and found this raised errors.
I could recommend you to use `trapz` method instead of `simps`.

But be careful firstly read about mathematical background for this two functions
[How to decide between scipy.integrate.simps or numpy.trapz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915116/how-to-decide-between-scipy-integrate-simps-or-numpy-trap).

If `trapz` will be suite for you, use it :)

Comment: Oh thank you, this is usefull! I've read and tried to use trapz instead of simps, but there is still one thing that seems strange. After evaluating the area with trapz, if I print it, I obtain a negative number.

Comment: I could recommend to read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973800/trapz-giving-weird-results

I hope it will be helpful for you :)

Comment: @XaBla I am using the np.trapz method which is giving me nan. My situation is same this question. Is there anything else that I can do?